# How to insert Data from textbox to MYSQL as HTML in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am using:
 `<textarea rows="24" name="thetext" cols="66"></textarea>`

After submitting, I send it to MYSQL in a cell type (longtext)...

For example: I input:

> Hello
>
> world

All I get in the variable is helloworld(one word)..
I need the line breaks..

I tried: `$results = htmlentities($_POST[thetext]);` and it is not working. How can I get it to show the line breaks please?

Comment: correct the implementation of text area like this `<textarea rows="24" name="thetext" cols="66"></textarea>`

Comment: have you tried $results =explode( "\r\n", $_POST['thetext'] );

Comment: Shouldn't this happen automatically?

Comment: there is no `<text area>` in html only we have is `<textarea>` tag

Comment: It was miss spelling <textarea> not <text area>

Comment: why dont you post some more codes of html form and place where you read html form datas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

correct the implementation of text area like this

`<textarea rows="24" name="thetext" cols="66"></textarea>`

and use

`nl2br($_POST[thetext])`

instead of

`htmlentities($_POST[thetext])`

Answer (score 1):

A textarea will send new lines using `\n\r`, you need to convert that to HTML before outputting it to a page using `nl2br($myVar);`

In this case if you do:

```
echo nl2br($_POST['thetext']);
```

you will get `Hello world` with the line breaks in.

Comment: I wanted to vote for you, but they again did not allow me, as this is my second question, I am new here

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to change your rows/cells in the database  to a ut8 collation charset. It should help you fix your problem.

Also the code I would use to send the form data to my database would be as follow:

```
$change_text = $_POST['thetext'];
$mysqli->query("YOUR_SQL_CODE");
```

And then to check if the data was sent correctly I would either access the row via the database directly or fetch the row like this:

```
if ($data = $mysqli->query("YOUR_SQL_CODE")) ;
$showtext = mysqli_fetch_row($data);
echo($showtext[0]);
```